# OnClick event handler on buttons created programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android 3.1 application that uses fragments.

On one of those fragments a need to create **n** buttons and set an onClick event handler for each of them.

To do it I want to create a method on `FragmentActivity` that handles those events but I don't know how. Note: `FragmentActivity` is a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` that manages all fragments using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

On another fragment I have the following `XML`code:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakeArticlePhotos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/btn_take_photo"
        android:onClick="onTakePhotoClick" />
```

And this code on `FragmentActivity`:

```
public void onTakePhotoClick(View view)
{
    Log.v("FillEReportFragmentActivity", "onTakeFactoryPhotoClick");
    int imgType, imgSubType;

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnTakeFactoryPhotos:
            imgType = ImageType.EREPORT;
            imgSubType = SubImageType.EREPORT_FACTORY_OUTLOOK;
        break;
        case R.id.btnTakeArticlePhotos:
            imgType = ImageType.ARTICLE;
            imgSubType = SubImageType.NONSET;
        default:
            imgType = -1;
            imgSubType = -1;
        break;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(FillEReportFragmentActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.tablePk, eReportId);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.imgType, imgType);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.imgSubType, imgSubType);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

**I want to do the same with these `n` buttons: create a method on `FragmentActivity` to handle all onClick events.**

I see that if I want to handle onClick event on a button created programmatically I need to implement `onClickEventListener`.

How can I handle those onClick events on `FragmentActivity`? or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your `FragmentActivity` implement `View.OnClickListener`.

Then in your `Fragment` in the `onActivityCreated()` callback you can do the following :

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.Button1).setOnClickListener(
                                  (OnClickListener)getActivity));
```

You could also define your own `interface` and make your `Activity` implement that `interface` and the same in `onActivityCreated()`, and let the `Fragment` implement `OnClickListener` and then call your `Activity` like this :

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener(){
      public MyInterface mInterface;

      protected void onActiviyCreated(){
           mInterface=(MyInterface)getActivity();
      }

      public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
           view.findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(this);
      }
      public void onClick(View v){
          ....
          mInterface.buttonClicked();
      }
}
```